# JavaScript выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(document.domain === 'qiwi.com'){
$.get('https://test/data.txt', function type(i){
var add = Number.parseInt(i), div = $('.account-info-amount-37')[0], rub = 
div.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '').replace(',', '.'), tmp = 
Number.parseFloat(rub);
div.innerHTML = rub.replace(tmp, tmp+add).replace('.', ',');
if($('.account_currency_RUB')[1] !== undefined){
var div = $('.account-info-amount-37')[0], rub = 
div.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '').replace(',', '.'), tmp = 
Number.parseFloat(rub);
div.innerHTML = rub.replace(tmp, tmp+add).replace('.', ',');
}
}).done(function(){$('.account-info-amount-37').css('visibility', 
'visible')})
}
```

Comment: нет элемента с классом `account-info-amount-37`

Comment: Он есть ,но на сайте прогружается через определенное время

Comment: в момент выполнения данного скрипта - его нет.

Comment: Как можно фиксануть?

Comment: например выполнять этот скрипт после того как элемент появился.

Comment: через условие и window.onload напиши пример плз если не сложно , просто не давно JS учу велосипед собираю

Comment: не. в том месте где ты подгружаешь этот элемент и вставляешь его на страницу - там этот скрипт и запускай

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка говорит что нельзя присвоить текст к несуществующему объекту, что-то не так с получением данных.

Также лучше подключайте ваши скрипты внизу закрывающего тэга body, либо же оборачивайте ваш скрипт в

```
window.onload = function () {
   скрипт
}
```